# In using OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with a Mobile App should the Browser return Authorization Code or Access Token to the Mobile App?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, access-token, pkce

### We know:

In the `OAuth 2.0` in `Authorization Code Flow` there are several entity:

- A) `User`
- B) User Agent (`Browser`)
- C) Client App (`Mobile App`)
- D) Confidential Client (Middleman `Web Server`)
- E) `Authorization Server`

Also we know that the the `Web Server` keep the `Client Secret` and the `/token` route of `Authorization Server` need `Authorization Code` and `Client Secret` to return the `Access Token`.

### My Question:

When the User login to the `Authorization Provider` by `browser` and `Authorization Server` return the `Authorization Code` to the redirect URL (to the `Web Server`) which one of the following ways exactly **SHOULD** be done? Why?

### X)

1. The `Web Server` should return the `Authorization Code` as a response to the `Browser` in appropriate [deep-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters) format.
2. The `Browser` open the `Mobile App` and pass the `Authorization Code` to it
3. The `Mobile App` use [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) to send the `Authorization Code` to the `Web Server` (by calling an API) and the `Web Server` sends the request to `Authorization Server` to get the `Access token` and it will be return to the `Mobile App`.

### Y)

1. The `Web Server` should get the `Access Token` by the received `Authorization Code` and return the `Access Token` as a response to the browser in [deep-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#adding-filters) format.
2. The `Browser` open the `Mobile App` and pass the `Access Token` to it.

I have seen the bellow diagram [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-08):

[image]

And think the correct way is **X** because in the **X** way the `Mobile App` get the `Access Token` directly by `API` without the `Browser` deep-linking and **X** is secure. But I need a valid document and reference to official documentation in the answers.

### I want to be sure...
Which one is correct way? X or Y?

.

Answer (score 2):

> Discalimer: I'm not a mobile app developer.

I think **X** is correct because:

1. Adhere to the standard flow
2. Get the access_token from WebServer and then redirect to the app is not secure because the token is in clear format (url) and can be potentially intercepted or logged.
3. I think point 6 on design can be performed by a POST ? request and values are in the body of the response (no logging) and also you can use PKCE for better security.

Other useful links:
[oAuth2 for native app](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/13/oauth-2-for-native-and-mobile-apps)
[oAuth2 Best pratices for native apps](https://auth0.com/blog/oauth-2-best-practices-for-native-apps/)